# if statement with include in handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to dynamically generate a series of checkboxes in hbs.  I have a bunch of arrays stored on a database and if the arrays contain the right numbers, I want a checkbox to be generated that has already been checked.

I've tried making a helper that just returns array.includes(num); and I've verified that everything works on that through logs, but if I plug my helper into an #if tag, I get one of many designer errors ranging from array.includes is not a function to ((depth0 && depth0.days_of_week) || alias2).call is not a function.  I've even tried making a bunch of semi-static helpers so that I only need to pass one parameter instead of two and that didn't make any difference.

```
hbs.registerHelper('daysOfWeek', (array, dayNum) => {
    return array.includes(dayNum);
});
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="0" {{#if daysOfWeek (this.days_of_week 0)}}checked{{/if}}>Sunday
<input type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="1" {{#if daysOfWeek (this.days_of_week 1)}}checked{{/if}}>Monday
```

...

Comment: have you tried putting a comma between `this.days_of_week` and `0`/`1`?

Comment: I did, to no avail.  The error I got was: Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'

Answer (score 3):

The syntax should be `{{#if (daysOfWeek days_of_week 0)}}checked{{/if}}`. Your helper function is correct.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="0" {{#if (daysOfWeek days_of_week 0)}}checked{{/if}}>Sunday
<input type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="1" {{#if (daysOfWeek days_of_week 1)}}checked{{/if}}>Monday
```

The `if` statement is checking the whole return of something, so in your case it is the helper function with two parameters: `(daysOfWeek days_of_week 0)`.

Comment: Oh ok.  That makes sense and totally fixed it, thank you.  Out of curiosity, do you know why 'this' isn't needed inside the if statement?

Comment: The `this` keyword is useful when iterating over an array for example, a reference to the current item. The property `days_of_week` is in this context (or 'global scope' you can say) directly available.